# How to set a deadline date for a work item?

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to directly assign a deadline date for a work item? 
Or can this only done by assigning the work item to an iteration?

Answer (score 4):

By default, AzDO does not contain a deadline date. However the similar field exists in the CMMI process: `Target Resolve Date` (in the Issue work item type). You can reuse it.

1. Create a new new process: [Create and manage inherited processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#create-an-inherited-process)
2. Add the existing field into your work item type:

[image]

3. Update you team project to use your new process: [Change the process used by a project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/manage-process?view=azure-devops#change-the-process-used-by-a-project)

Or add your own `Deadline Date` as Mario mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

afaik, this can be only achieved with an iteration. If, for some reason, you need an additional field defining a dead line, you can edit your Process and create a new field of type Date/Time and add it to your work items.

Go to Organization Settings -> Process -> (create an inherited process, if not already) -> edit a work item -> New field ... then reuse this field on other work items where needed